# Show only updated files since last visit & remove flag once clicked

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a list of .html files that are updated every so often.

I am looking for the best way to show that they have been updated since the user's last visit by adding a class to the `<li>`.

Currently I am dropping a cookie for `lastVisit` with the relevant date / time and can show the files that have been updated by comparing the time the file was changed to the `lastVisit`in the cookie.

As soon as the user clicks to view one of the files and returns to the list though, all of the 'updated' flags have been reset (as a the cookie is updated with the current date / time) so it looks as if none are updated.

Is there a way to show the updated state and remove the updated flag when they have visited the actual page but leave the rest showing?

The method & logic currently escape me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.